# create tablespace :Unknown object type 'TABLESPACE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement

Tags: sql-server

I try to create a tablespace in  Microsoft SQL server and it didn't work - I get this error:

> Unknown object type 'TABLESPACE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ruqaiya
DATAFILE 'c:\ ruqaiya.dbf'
SIZE 20m;
```

Comment: Where in [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server does not have tablespaces only datafiles and secondary datafiles.

Comment: ok What is the alternative for tablespaces

Comment: Are you new to sql server? What databases do you know. Here's a comparison between oracle and sqlserver that might help, but you should maybe read through the basics of sqlserver.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3597/comparison-of-sql-server-and-oracle-terminology/